# To enable syntax highlighting with color for JBehave stories in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testing, syntax-highlighting, jbehave

how to configure the IDE settings to recognize.story files (or any other file extension you're using for JBehave stories) and associate them with a text editor that supports syntax highlighting.

I tried running my .story files . All code is in black and cannot move to next function on click+enter .

Answer (score 0):

To enable syntax highlighting for JBehave stories in Eclipse: You can Install JBehave Eclipse Plugin (Optional):There's a JBehave Eclipse Plugin available that provides features like syntax highlighting and step completion. You can install it from the Eclipse Marketplace or through the Eclipse IDE.

**Associate File Extension:** Ensure that your JBehave story files have the correct file extension (usually `.story`). Right-click on a `.story` file in Eclipse and select `Open With` > `Other...`. Choose a text editor (such as the default Text Editor or any other preferred editor).

**Configure Syntax Highlighting:** Once you've associated the `.story` files with a text editor, you may need to configure the syntax highlighting preferences. Go to `Window` > `Preferences` > `General` > `Editors` > `File Associations`. Here, you can select the file type (e.g., "*.story") and associate it with the text editor.

After configuring the syntax highlighting preferences, click `Apply` or `OK` to save the changes.

The above solution worked for me .